# 4 pin square plug

Tags: connector, identification

Anyone know what this plug is?

[image]

Comment: Information about dimensions, pitch, anything?
Looks like a "4 pin atx power connector" can't be sure without specs

Comment: Molex mini-fit jr, but need measurements to confirm.

Comment: Could also be Mini Universal Mate-N-LOK  https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-housings/319?k=mate+n+lock&k=&pkeyword=mate+n+lock&s=4518&pv88=6&FV=ffe0013f&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25

Comment: It is the Minifit Jr.  You can tell by the position of the roundings that serve to ensure correct orientation.

Comment: This doesn't even look like *your* photo. Did you take this picture from somewhere? Did that *somewhere* provide any details about the picture?

Comment: Additional information was requested, but wasn't provided by the O.P.  Closing.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like molex mini-fit JR series, with custom molding

[image: Digikey WM3701-MD]

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/39-01-2040/WM3701-ND/61376

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Worcester Bosch blue plug, see

> https://www.advancedwater.co.uk/spare-512-004-0004.html